# There is this song that I can't find the Pinyin lyrics to on Youtube

Tags: translation, mandarin, simplified-characters, pinyin, songs

Can someone help me find it please? This is just copied and pasted from what should be the songs title 凌震 尤金 多看一眼

Comment: Any particular reason you like this song? Just curious.

Comment: I fell in love with it. I took Mandarin for 2 years and this brought back a lot of memories for me that I miss. I would love to learn it again. This song has touched me.

Answer (score 1):

To find pinyin for the lyrics, just  input it in Google Translate

Example: At Google Translate: [多看一眼](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%A4%9A%E7%9C%8B%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC&op=translate)

> 多看一眼

> Duō kàn yīyǎn

If you don't have the lyrics, search Google for 多看一眼 歌词 and you will get it [here](https://mojim.com/twy100515x5x14.htm)

鳳飛飛

多看一眼

作詞：莊奴/ 作曲：湯尼

```
青山高　綠水長　藍天白雲好風光
芳草綠　鮮花香　比不上可愛的好姑娘
眼睛大　明又亮　神情好像水蕩漾
身材美　健又壯　烏黑的頭髮飄肩上
你看她一眼　一輩子都在想
她看你一眼　一輩子不會忘
誰不愛　好姑娘　美麗溫柔又大方
你若是　真愛她　緊緊的跟在她身旁
```

Also, just search YouTube for 多看一眼 and I got this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9D0GFTt-DA) with pinyin (but no tone)

凌震 and 尤金 are two singers who also sang this song but 鳳飛飛 was the original singer

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I am forever grateful. You have made my day.

Comment: @Lynjah Marie Saint This has a higher quality picture and actual singing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9D0GFTt-DA BTW, you can see there is a whole list of the same songs in the search YouTube result.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now learning this will be so much more easy.